# Can't not start logstash when enable security At elastic search and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk, logstash-file

I'm try to using Security function at ELK. My elastic version is 7.5.1

I'm having a problem with the file config. i can't start logstash

1.First, i enable security in `elasticsearch.yml` by added `xpack.security.enabled: true`

2.Second, at `kibana.yml` i edit `elasticsearch.username` = "elasctic" and `elasticsearch.password` is my set up password

I start service elasticsearch and kibana.
still here everythings is ok.

3.Then i run my logstash with the conf below:

```
    input {
        file {
                path => ["/etc/logstash/handleexception1.txt"]
        type => "_doc"
                start_position => beginning
        }
}
filter {
        dissect {
            mapping => {
                "message" => "%{Date} %{Time} %{INFO} %{Service} Message:%{Message} ExceptionList:%{ExceptionList}"
            }
        }
}
output {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstashhhandlerror2"
        user => "elastic"
        pasword => "elastic"
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug}
}
```

acctually i was try both

```
input {
elasticsearch{
    file {
            path => ["/etc/logstash/handleexception1.txt"]
    type => "_doc"
            start_position => beginning
    }
user => "elastic"
password => "elastic"
}
}

filter {
    elasticsearch{
        dissect {
            mapping => {
                "message" => "%{Date} %{Time} %{INFO} %{Service} Message:%{Message} ExceptionList:%{ExceptionList}"
            }
        }
    user => "elastic"
    password => "elastic"
    }
}
output {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstashhhandlerror2"
        user => "elastic"
        pasword => "elastic"
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Here is the screen when i try to start logtash.service

[image]

Thanks for reading and hoping you have ask for my problem.

Comment: Acctual i started but can't create any INDEX :( so that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your point 3 config should be working only you need to make one change for index creation, update output:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "logstashhhandlerror2"
      user => "elastic"
      pasword => "elastic"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug}
  }
 }
```